# Is it a metaphor or not?

Tags: metaphor

> Ich bin gespannt wie ein Bettlaken

Is this metaphor or not?

From [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/metaphor/):

> - A metaphor states that one thing is another thing
> - It equates those two things not because they actually are the same, but for the sake of comparison or symbolism
> - If you take a metaphor literally, it will probably sound very strange (are there actually any sheep, black or otherwise, in your
>     family?)
> - Metaphors are used in poetry, literature, and anytime someone wants to add some color to their language

In my opinion, the sentence above can't be a metaphor. But everyone in my company keeps telling me it is one. So please can someone bring light into this issue?

Why I think it is not a metaphor:
The word `gespannt` has different meanings: stretched and excited in English. In the context of `Bettlaken` only the meaning for stretched can be applied. But in context of `Ich bin` only the other meaning makes sense. So it's not the case that the same meaning is transmitted into another context.

If compared to `gebrochenes Herz` (broken heart), which is a metaphor: A heart can not literally get broken. So the word `broken` is used as a symbol. But a `Bettlaken` can be `gespannt`. What symbol could that be?

The intention was probably to say

> I am *very* excited

But a `Bettlaken` can be `gespannt` properly or less properly. It gives no clue whether the person is *very* excited or only excited on a normal level.

1.) Stating that one thing is another thing:
Does not apply here. Because `I` is not said to be something else then the person who speaks this sentence.

2.) Equation of two things **for the sake of comparison or symbolism**: Does not apply. Bed sheets can never be curious or excited. So no symbol is used here.

3.) It does sound strange if taken literally.

4.) May apply here, too.

Comment: I just wanna throw the obligatory "Gespannt wie ein Flitzebogen" out there, which should be clearer in terms of how "gespannt" it is.

Answer (score 3):

This is a metaphor. What your mind seems to stumble about is the fact, that it is also a *catachresis* ([de: wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katachrese), [en: wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catachresis)). The term *catachresis* has a couple of different (but similar) meanings. I am referring to the definition that a catachresis is a metaphor perceived as dissonant, where either two parts in the allegoric domain of the metaphor do not fit semantically or where the allegoric domain does not seem to fit to the literal domain of the metaphor.

The point here is, that *gespannt* is used in two meanings, which have quite some conceptual distance: The "Bettlaken" is "gespannt" in a very mechanical way, while "Ich" is "gespannt" in a merely figurative way. The sentence

> Ich bin gespannt wie ein Bettlaken.

emphasises this distance of the literal and the figurative meaning and thus renews the catachrestic aspects of the figurative meaning of *gespannt*. The catachresis is further intensified by the fact that "Bettlaken" does not stand prototypical for things which come to your mind if you think about something which is "gespannt": Even though it is totally normal to use the verb *spannen* with the object *Bettlaken* and there is even the word *Spannbetlaken*, the idea of "tension" which is the source of the figurative meaning of *gespannt* is not prototypically represented in a "Spannbettlaken", but rather in a spring. The concept of *Spannbettlaken* does not have the idea of this inner tension, and this is the source of the catachresis here, I would say.

Comment: Ich bin überzeugt wie ein lügender Beschuldigter.  Darum bin ich jetzt verstimmt wie eine Harfe. (Man weiß ja: Die Harfenistin stimmt immer. Die Harfe stimmt nie.)

Comment: I contradict your last sentence, as a lot of Bettlaken are "Spannbettlaken". With this in mind the sentence contains another play on words.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Auch der Harfenist stimmt immer. Die Harfe stimmt höchstens eine Stunde, oder bis ein Fenster geöffnet wird.

Comment: @mtwde I don't see a contradiction between what you say and the last sentence of my post. But I added a more detailed explanation of my claim.

Comment: @harper Aber ja. Darum geht es ja in diesem Aphorismus. (Harfenistin ist übrigens die moderne Form, sowohl Harfenisten als auch Harfenistinnen anzusprechen. Ich frage mich nur, ob der Harf sich nicht am Ende übergangen fühlt.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann OT: Ich fühle mich dadurch aber nicht angesprochen sondern ausgegrenzt. Und nur weil es jetzt "in Mode" ist, würde ich es nicht als die "moderne Form" nennen, wenn ein paar Leute den Unterschied zwischen biologischem Geschlecht und grammatikalischen Genus nicht kapieren. Ich möchte aber nicht diese Frage hier missbrauchen und hier weiterdiskutieren.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Irgendwie schätze ich deinen humorigen Kommentar. Er trägt jedoch nichts zur Verbesserung des Beitrags bei. Magst du ihn löschen?

Answer (score 2):

Nein, das ist keine Metapher, sondern ein *bildhafter Vergleich*.

Der Unterschied zur Metapher besteht darin, dass der Vergleich explizit gemacht wird:

> Ich bin gespannt **wie** ein Bettlaken.

Bettlaken und Flitzebogen sind wohl als bildhafte Vergleiche nicht etabliert genug, um auch metaphorisch eingesetzt zu werden. Dagegen:

> Du bist meine Morgensonne.

wäre eine Metapher, während

> Du bist wie die Morgensonne für mich.

wieder ein bildhafter Vergleich wäre.